# How to fetch rows in column manner in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a record in my table like

```
memberId    PersonId    Year
4057        1787         2
4502        1787         3
```

I want a result from a query like this

```
memberId1   MemberId2   PersonId
4057        4502        1787
```

How to write a query ??

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this in a query, do it in the application layer.

Comment: how to do this ? can u explain ?

Comment: Clearly it depends on the number of records involved. I would strongly advice against doing this in the application layer for big record-sets.

Comment: I disagree, I think you can play with it & see what works, how often it is done etc

Comment: @vivek - you'll need to specify what language you are using

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in SQL. At best you can try:

```
SELECT table1.memberId memberId1, table2.memberId MemberId2, PersonId
FROM table table1 JOIN table table2 USING (PersonId)
```

But it won't do what you expect if you have more than 2 Members for a person. (It will return every possible combination.)

Answer (score 0):

Below an example on how to do it directly in SQL. Mind that there is plenty of room for optimisation but this version should be rather fast, esp if you have an index on PersonID and year.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,
                memberId1 = Convert(int, NULL),
                memberId2 = Convert(int, NULL)
  INTO #result
  FROM myTable
 WHERE Year IN (2 , 3)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0_result ON #result (PersonID) 

UPDATE #result 
   SET memberId1 = t.memberId
  FROM #result upd
  JOIN myTable t
    ON t.PersionId = upd.PersonID
   AND t.Year = 2

UPDATE #result 
   SET memberId2 = t.memberId
  FROM #result upd
  JOIN myTable t
    ON t.PersionId = upd.PersonID
   AND t.Year = 3

SELECT * FROM #result
```

Comment: You do not need a clustered index for this. A regular one will do just fine and will probably be faster.

Comment: You got me curious and I did some tests on some sample data (replaced PersonID with object_id, memberId with user_type_id and myTable with sys.columns on a largish database. (returns around 2000 records). Turns out it doesn't make any difference on the query plan, and the STATISTICS TIME are pretty much the same too. Although I agree that the creation of the index will be slightly slower when clustered (more IO), in my experience it's usually faster afterwards (if the index is appropriate!) as there is no need for bookmark-lookups and also because it seems MSSQL simply doesn't like heaps. IMHO

Comment: A clustered index is used (helps) when you need to return the result set in a particular order. But you can only have one such index on the table. It is premature to declare that personID should be that column. Even without knowing more about this application I can say that it's quite rare to have to return a result set sorted by an arbitrary ID such as personID. I would only create a clustered index after I know which column is the one that gets sorted in order. If I didn't know which column that is, I would not use a clustered index and leave it as an option for later.

Comment: It was not faster in your test because your are not sorting the result, so a clustered index does nothing, and it actually slows things (if you have inserts and updates) since you have to maintain the physical order of the table (although an ID column is always in order so that doesn't apply here). I don't know anything about mssql and heaps, but it would be odd for that to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all member ids for each person_id, you could use [for xml path] statement (great functionality)
to concat all memberId s in a string

```
select distinct PersonId
       , (select ' '+cast(t0.MemberId as varchar)
          from table t0 
          where t0.PersonId=t1.PersonId
          for xml path('')
         ) [Member Ids]
from table t1
```

resulting in:

```
PersonId   Members Ids
1787      ' 4057 4502'
```

if you really need seperate columns, with unlimited number of memberIds, consider using
a PIVOT table, but far more complex to use